# Flask not importing in virtualenv

Tags: python, flask

Installing flask:

```
(cloud_computing)  ⚙     master  pip install Flask  
Collecting Flask
  Using cached Flask-0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.21 in ./cloud_computing/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=2.0 in ./cloud_computing/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.7 in ./cloud_computing/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.4 in ./cloud_computing/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./cloud_computing/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask)
Installing collected packages: Flask
Successfully installed Flask-0.12
```

Checking if installed

```
(cloud_computing)  ⚙     master  pip list         
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
appdirs (1.4.3)
click (6.7)
Flask (0.12)
geopy (1.11.0)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.9.5)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
oauthlib (2.0.1)
packaging (16.8)
pip (9.0.1)
pyparsing (2.2.0)
requests (2.13.0)
requests-oauthlib (0.8.0)
setuptools (34.3.2)
six (1.10.0)
tweepy (3.5.0)
Werkzeug (0.12)
wheel (0.29.0)



 (cloud_computing)  ⚙     master  pip show Flask
    Name: Flask
    Version: 0.12
    Summary: A microframework based on Werkzeug, Jinja2 and good intentions
    Home-page: http://github.com/pallets/flask/
    Author: Armin Ronacher
    Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
    License: BSD
    Location: /home/abhishek/Dropbox/columbia_docs/cloud_computing/cloud_computing_twittmap/cloud_computing/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    Requires: itsdangerous, click, Werkzeug, Jinja2
```

Import error!!!

```
(cloud_computing)  ⚙     master  python -c "import Flask"          
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named Flask

(cloud_computing)  ✘ ⚙     master  python -c "import flask"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "flask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name Flask
```

My virtualenv is activated as (cloud_computing) displays at the prompt. Not sure what the issue is here. Saw other questions on stack on this, but with no useful response for my case.

Comment: It is `import flask` with a lowercase `f`, **not** `import Flask`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: You have a `flask.py` file in your directory, delete that.

Comment: See [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](//stackoverflow.com/q/36250353)